# Derivative $e^{-1/(1-x^2)}$

Tags: functions, derivatives

Prove that limit of $n$-th derivative of the function $f(x)=e^{(-1/(1-x^2))}$ at points $x=-1+0$ and $x=1-0$
are zero.  $\lim_{x \to -1+0}f^{(k)}(x)=0 , \lim_{x \to 1-0}f^{(k)})=0 $

I found the limits of first and second derivatives:

$$\lim_{x \to -1+0}f'(x)=\lim_{x \to 1-0}f'(x)=\lim_{x \to -1+0}f''(x)=\lim_{x \to 1-0}f''(x)=0$$

But what about the general case?

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$f^{\prime}(x) = -\frac{2 e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}} x}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}$$ and $$f^{\prime \prime}(x) = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}} \left(6 x^4-2\right)}{\left(x^2-1\right)^4}$$

Comment: ??  I have already found the first and second derivative.

Comment: Prove by induction that $f^{(n)}=r_n(1-x^2)f(x)$, where $r_n$ is a rational function. Then you can prove in general that for every rational function $r$ the limit of $r(t)e^{-1/t}$ is zero, when $t\to0^+$. This is because you can just bound $|r(t)|\leq Ct^{-K}$, for some constants $C,K$ and the limit of $t^{-K}e^{-1/t}$ you can compute, say using Bernouilli's inequality.

Comment: Please, may you clarify what you mean by $x = -1 + 0$ and $x = 1 - 0$? I suppose you mean points $x=-1$ and $x=1$, right?

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto It is a common infinitesimal-inspired language meaning limit from the right $-1+0$ of $-1$ and from the left $1-0$ of $1$. Some others use $-1^+$ and $1^-$, respectively.

Comment: Oh, I see. I prefer the latter because it requires less space. The second is possible in editors without superscript.